# SQLException: Protocol violation. Oracle JDBC Driver issue

Tags: java, oracle, exception, jdbc

I'm getting the following excpetion:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:145)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:190)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:286)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C80all.receive(T4C80all.java:766)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.do0all8(T4CPreparedStatement.java:216)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CPreparedStatement.fetch(T4CPreparedStatement.java:1225)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.close_or_fetch_from_next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:373)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleResultSetImpl.next(OracleResultSetImpl.java:284)
```

The Oracle system is running 10.2.0.3.0 on Solaris 5.10. The jdbc driver is running on JDK 1.6.0_21 (if it's import the java is running on a Solaris 5.10 machine as well). I've tried several different oracle thin drivers including the latest and the one that appears to exactly match the oracle version.

The query I'm running is fairly simple: "select * from some_table order by key1, key2, key3" Then iterating through the result set and writing to a file. The table has around 12 million rows, so I expect the process is running long, but it seems to die within 5-15 mins into it. Each time I run it, it blows up on a different row, so I don't think the problem is with the data.

I found the oracle alert log but I couldn't tell that anything in there was related to my process. Still, I'm no oracle expert and perhaps there's an oracle setting I need to look at. Strangely enough, I'm running about five of these type of queries (a couple are a bit more complicated) on different connections and only two simplest ones ever get this problem.

Any help or ideas on what to look at to narrow down the problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps you are running out of memory on the DB server? Are you properly closing the resources in Java? Is this happening on the first query run in your series or one of the later ones?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Apparently adding -d64 to the java command line fixes this problem. Looks like a Solaris 64-bit issue.

Comment: For me, upgrading my ojdbc driver fixed this. I jumped to 11.2.0.2.0 and all was fine.

Answer (score 8):

For future googlers who are have to this page, here is the problem we had .
The protocol violation exception was being logged on application logs and Oracle trace.

**Oracle trace**

This is error from oracle trace files

--- PROTOCOL VIOLATION DETECTED ---

```
----- Dump Cursor sql_id=1j5kjnkncpp xsc=0x2a053a2a0 cur=0x2a052f1cf0 ---
----- Current SQL Statement for this session (sql_id=1jjns4k6npp) -----
        select xyz
```

**From Application Logs**

```
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.UncategorizedSQLException: SqlMapClient operation; uncategorized SQLException for SQL []; SQL state [72000]; error code [20000];
```

**Symptom**

This exception was happening occasionally. The stack trace had different sql in it which was very confusing. Running the sql with sql plus worked fine.

**Root Cause**

The exception was thrown when oracle driver was trying to export a CLOB data. This was happening with only few records, not all of them. The data as such was a file. Visually we could not make out what was wrong with that data.

**Why we were seeing errors in oracle logs ?**

So if this was a driver defect, why did we see the error in oracle trace ? Logically the driver errors should be only confined to application logs.
The reasons was that when protocol violation happened, the connection got corrupted. This connection was returned to the connection pool. Any user or job when will use that connection would not work and would experience error.
That is why it will happen at random places, with random users

**Solution**

A short term fix was to change this property in connection pool. We are using DBCP connection pool.

Changed from 
ds.setTestOnBorrow(false);
to 
ds.setTestOnBorrow(true);

Now when the pool returns a corrupted connection to the pool, before app borrows this connection , it would test for validity. If connection is unusable, pool would discard and then app gets a new/valid connection.

If you enable connection pool logs, you should see the exception which normally is swallowed.

**Driver Upgrade**

Upgrade to OJDBC 12.1.0.2  from  OJDBC 12.1.0.1 solved the problem, even for the problematic rows.

Some other links for reference

https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/CONFKB/java.sql.SQLException%3A+Protocol+violation+caught+while+accessing+a+page+and+Oracle+DB+is+used

Answer (score 0):

In my case, using tomcat 8.5 (standard connection pool), oracle 19, when oracle emits an warning message (like 'your password will expire in n days'), the java connection object interprets like an error.

I just change the PASSWORD, by the same name, and the problem was solved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).