# cannot create a functioning connection pool with glassfish

Tags: java, oracle, glassfish, connection-pooling

I'm trying to create a connection pool from glassfish to Oracle.
When I use command line, all seems to work during the creation, but the application crashed with this exception:

`Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Protocol violation
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:450)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:186)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C7Ocommoncall.doOROLLBACK(T4C7Ocommoncall.java:68)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection.doRollback(T4CConnection.java:642)
            at oracle.jdbc.driver.PhysicalConnection.rollback(PhysicalConnection.java:3716)
            at com.sun.gjc.spi.base.ConnectionHolder.rollback(ConnectionHolder.java:630)
            at  org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollbackAndResetAutoCommit(JDBCTransaction.java:217)
            at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.rollback(JDBCTransaction.java:196)`

**EDIT**: This exception is trowed when the application try to do a rollback, using JPA. **END EDIT**

This is the command I used to create the CP:

    `asadmin> create-jdbc-connection-pool --restype javax.sql.DataSource
    --datasourceclassname oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource
    --property "user=myUser:password=myPw:url=jdbc\\:oracle\\:thin\\:@dbHostName\\:1521\\:mySID" My_CP`

I tried also to create the CP from the admin gui (that would be more user friendly), but even if I copied the ojdbc6.jar in /opt/glassfish3_old/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib, when I have to select the driver classname the corresponding selection list is empty!

**EDIT**: 
I'm using:
java version "1.7.0_06"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_06-b24)
Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)

and glassfish 3.1.2.2 oracle version (but with the 3.1.2 open source version, it behaves the same)
**END EDIT**

Probably I'm doing a stupid error somewhere.

Can anyone have a suggestion?

Comment: Similar Thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4685021/sqlexception-protocol-violation-oracle-jdbc-driver-issue

Comment: May also be a driver bug: https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2248536&start=0&tstart=0

Comment: Thaks Mike. I read the links, but they are not my case.

Comment: Have you copied the drivers to the correct directory and restarted the instance?  http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2432/gkyan.html

Comment: Yes, I do it. I copied the ojdbc6.jar in the lib directory of my domain. And I expected from that I can create without problem the CP from the gui, but the selection list of the driver classname remain empty, so I cannot choose thin library.

Comment: One more link for you http://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-10626

Comment: Remove the space from before 'url' in your property string, if for no other reason than to be "clean".

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
url=jdbc\\:oracle\\:thin\\:@dbHostName\\:1521\\:mySID
```

try with following pattern?

```
jdbc:oracle:thin:@dbHostName:1521:mySID
```

Comment: It's the same. The creation works, but when I use the cp through the application, it crash. I'm wondering why it does not use thin driver, as I setted.